# Return information using a submit button in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, forms

I am working on a web application that asks for user input and returns information based on their selection. I have two checkboxes which ask for country and state. When these two conditions are fulfilled, a submit button should return information based on the country and state.

My problem is, how do i make the submit button take the inputted information and translate it into data(results) on the next page? I have a search.html and a search_results.html. Do I need a search.html or can I just go from selectCountry.html to the search_results.html based on the input info?

I am using HTML, angularJs, and Javascript. To better understand my question, my link is http://travel-buddy.us/selectCountry.html, [the submit button does not do anything yet].

selectcountry.html

```
    <form id= "myForm" method="get">
        <div class="col-2">
            <label>
                Country
                 <select id="country" name="country"></select>
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-2">
            <label>
                 State/City
                 <select name="state" id="state"></select>
            </label>
            <script src = "js/countries.js" language="javascript">
                populateCountries("country", "state");
                populateCountries("country2");
            </script>
            <script language="javascript">
                populateCountries("country", "state");
            </script>
        </div>
    </form>
    <a href="./try.html" class="btn btn-primary btn-xl page-scroll">SUBMIT</a>
</header>
```

countries.js

```
function populateStates( countryElementId, stateElementId ){

    var selectedCountryIndex = document.getElementById( countryElementId ).selectedIndex;

    var stateElement = document.getElementById( stateElementId );

    stateElement.length=0;
    stateElement.options[0] = new Option('Select State','');
    stateElement.selectedIndex = 0;

    var state_arr = s_a[selectedCountryIndex].split("|");

    for (var i=0; i<state_arr.length; i++) {
        stateElement.options[stateElement.length] = new Option(state_arr[i],state_arr[i]);
    }
}

function populateCountries(countryElementId, stateElementId){
    // given the id of the <select> tag as function argument, it inserts <option> tags
    var countryElement = document.getElementById(countryElementId);
    countryElement.length=0;
    countryElement.options[0] = new Option('Select Country','-1');
    countryElement.selectedIndex = 0;

    for (var i=0; i<country_arr.length; i++) {
        countryElement.options[countryElement.length] = new Option(country_arr[i],country_arr[i]);
    }

    // Assigned all countries. Now assign event listener for the states.

    if( stateElementId ){
        countryElement.onchange = function(){
            populateStates( countryElementId, stateElementId );
        };
    }        
}
```

search.html

```
<html ng-app="searchApp">
    <!-- This page uses AngularJS -->
    <head>
        <title>::SEARCH::</title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="/js/search-control.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/style.css">
    </head>

    <body ng-controller="UserCtrl">
        <div>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="text" ng-model="user_input"></td>
                <button ng-click="search(user_input)">Search</button>
            </tr>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

search_result.html

```
<html ng-app="searchApp">
    <!-- This page uses AngularJS -->
    <head>
        <title>::SEARCH::</title>
        <script   src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="/js/search-control.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/style.css">
    </head>

    <body ng-controller="UserCtrl">
        <div>

         <h1>{{pageContent.pageTitle}}</h1>
        <p>{{pageContent.description}}</p>
        <img src={{pageContent.picUrl}}></img>

        <p>::Top 3 Things To Do::</p>
        <div ng-repeat="todo in pageContent.thingsToDo">
             <a href = {{todo.url}}> {{todo.activity}} </a> 
          </div>

          <p>::Top 3 Restaurants::</p>
        <div ng-repeat="restaurant in pageContent.restaurants">
            <a href = {{restaurant.url}}> {{restaurant.name}} </a>
          </div>

          <p>::Page source::</p>
          <a href = {{pageContent.sourceUrl}}> source </a>

        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Include just enough code to allow others to reproduce the problem. For help with this, read How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.
If it is possible to create a live example of the problem that you can link to (for example, on http://sqlfiddle.com/ or http://jsbin.com/) then do so - but also include the code in your question itself. Not everyone can access external sites, and the links may break over time.

Comment: You are using angular.I dont understand why you need page refresh?

Answer (score 0):

Set the ng-model values for the input for easy access.

You can use window.location to take these data to the next page.

**In HTML**

```
<select id="country" name="country" ng-model="country">
</select>
<select name="state" id="state" ng-model="state">
</select>

<button ng-click="goToNextPg()">SUBMIT</button>
```

**In the Controller**

```
$scope.goToNextPg = function () {
    window.location="#/search_results/country="+$scope.country+"&&state="+$scope.state;
}
```

Note:

1. search_results    - The path to your next page.
2. country and state - The key value pairs.

To access these values in the next page,

```
var country = $location.search()['country'];
var state = $location.search()['state'];
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your feedback, truly appreciate it. I have a question, since you say search_results will be the path, does this mean i have no need for search.html. In selectCountry.html, i made <a href =" ./search_results.html", is this right? In essence, I am asking if the search.html will be rendered useless if i can just retrieve results directly from search.html. My search-control.js code http://jsbin.com/vomuqiquki/edit?html,js,output